# Custom Query pagination 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I am struggling with the pagination of a custom loop in WordPress … 

The Links are displayer correctly, but when I click on the next page I get a 404 Error.

The Link seems to be correct http://…/page/2/

Did I miss something while creating the query? 

Do I have to add an additional function in the functions.php file?

This is my query:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
$wu_media_query = new WP_Query( );
$wu_media_query->query('showposts=5&post_type=wu_media&paged=' . $paged);
```

Would be grateful any hint :-) 

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, go to ***Settings >> Permalinks*** and hit **Save Changes** button. Sometime you need to regenerate you `.htaccess` file to make the pagination work.

Make sure you've called `wp_reset_query()` after ending the `while` loop or after the default ***WordPress*** loop. Sometimes it make this kinda trouble.

Pass `'paged' => $paged` with the query arguments array to the `WP_Query`

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'category_name' => 'tutorials',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged // Like this.
);
```

Remember, for custom pages that are **NOT** static home pages, the `$paged` variable changes to this:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Hope the above helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response 
Tried it, but it didn't help …
After a cleanup and a lot of trial and error I got it to work 